Is it possible to replace the flat-top pins on flat pedals with ones that have a dome top?
Is it possible to replace the flat-top pins on flat pedals with ones that have a dome top?
I'm finding that SPD pedals are a bad idea — for me. If I make a mistake while trying something new, I'm much more likely to go down with the bike. But unclipped I feel a lot safer, which in turn makes me experiment more.
But if I miss catching a flat pedal at the right moment, and it hits my shin, it's a nasty tear, hence my search for pins that provide grip, but ones that won't rip my skin.
Context
Three years ago I followed the advice of Paul H in a comment: "You seem to underestimate the chaos of technical mountain bike terrain," and chose double-sided SPD pedals for single track mountain biking. I'm now convinced that clipless pedals are the wrong choice while learning. Flat pedals are best. But I have enough scars from past experiments with flat pedals, hence the question.
Clarification (edit)
Wearing MTB-specific shoes when riding with flat MTB pedals is a good idea, but most or all wounds I've had from pedal pins occurred because I was unable to catch a pedal in time, not because I caught the tip of the pedal with the tip of my shoes and slipped. In other words, wearing better shoes is not a solution to this problem. The shape of the pins (or, failing that, protection) is.
Basically I'd like to replace the bolts on an MTB pedal such as the
PD-GR500 with pins that have the following elevation and side-view.


For reference: if unclipping is the main concern, two things to try first: lower the amount of force required to unclip (there's a bolt that allows to adjust that, one per side), and changing the cleats. Shimano has two kinds: SH51, that only release in one direction/plan, and SH56 that can be release in multiple direction.

What kind of shoes were you wearing in your previous flat pedal experiemets?

@PaulH I was wearing tennis shoes, but they always had rather supple rubber. Do the soles of non-clipped-in cycling shoes mate particularly well with pedal studs? Either way only a fraction of the pins will find a groove inside the sole; no?

@Sam7919 FiveTen’s stealth rubber is especially grippy and its rebound is well-suited to maintaining contact with the pins when temporarily unweighted. The shallow-dotted tread pattern ensures good contact with the pins as well. “Supple” rubber doesn’t necessarily mean “good” in this context.

@PaulH Can you explain how that works? Do the pins on pedals act like Lego-pins, entering snuggly into the gaps in the soles of the shoes? For that to work they'd almost have to be mated in dimensions (with sales buzz words). I'm guessing that some pins will find a spot between three-circles in the Five Ten soles, but most won't. It's just that the rubber is supple enough to allow the pins to be buried, without the pins protruding into the foot.

@Sam7919 The rubber is very soft. Just a little firmer than a rock climbing shoe.

You’d have to see what type of pins your pedals use and find suitable replacements. Some thread in from the top, some thread in from the bottom, some are fully threaded vs partially, some have the tool fitting on the top vs bottom… make sure you match all those parameters. An alternative idea is to grind down your existing pins. This may not be possible if for example the tool fitting is at the tip of the pin.
However, I really don’t believe the shape of the pin tip will make any appreciable difference. Maybe a rounded tip won’t break the skin if you just brush your leg against the pedal, but with anything more than that, the forces involved will be enough to impale you regardless of tip shape. Also, consider that over time, grinding your pedals on rocks and stuff will resharpen the pin tips, and so you’ll need to replace or re-round them on an ongoing basis. You may be better off wearing long pants or some kind of shin guards instead.

I reckon the inevitably damaged edges of the existing pins are probably worse even than their original shape, and agree that new pins of any shape won't be better for long

Just confirming... I'm well-aware of football (aka soccer) shin guards, but there is no such thing as cycling shin guards; is that right? Football shin guards would be rather awkward on a bike.

@Sam7919 Oh, but there are. Watch any downhill race. The riders there could easily participate in any medieval tournament with their armour. But jokes aside, there is a very wide variety of protective gear for MTB riding, from specialty shoes all the way to full face helmets and goggles.

@arne I see it now https://www.google.com/search?q=mtb+shin+guards . Thanks. I have the impression that if I wear one of these, I'd basically be declaring that I intend to hurt myself.

@Sam7919 it would seem the opposite to me

@Sam7919 You could say the same about wearing a helmet or any other safety equipment. End of the day, it's your safety on the line!

@PaulH (and at-MaplePanda) A helmet is not negotiable. That's where I'm starting. My point is that if I start to protect just my shins, where will the end be? My elbows are also kind of critical. My wrists are very critical. You get the idea.

@Sam7919 And there is absolutely no shame in wearing all that. Only self-conscious children seriously care about looking silly because of wearing extra safety equipment. As the safety waivers say, mountain biking is an inherently risky activity, and there's no reason you should be judged for recognizing that fact.

@MaplePanda It's hardly a question of self-consciousness, or, worse, of shame. Mainly it's that I don't take that much risk and I don't ride trails so advanced to warrant full armor. It's also a question of temperature regulation. I reluctantly started wearing long-sleeves in the summer, just to have a minimal layer between my blood and the mud, just in case. I wouldn't want to be wearing more than that until late October.

@MaplePanda (we're about to be reminded to move to chat, but here goes) I'm curious: do you wear full armor all the time, or just when you're trying new techniques?

@Sam7919 You don't need to wear full armor just to get shin protection. There are plenty of standalone options available.

@MaplePanda I reckon Sam's point is that if you're going to protect your shins, there are other areas of the body you'd be equally likely to want to protect, so you'd end up with rather a lot of you covered in padded plastic.  I'm another rider who runs really hot, and just goes for helmet and light gloves, but I end up covered in nettle stings and bramble scratches

I completely agree with MaplePanda that domed metal pin is any less likely to do shin damage than a flat top if one were to slip off the pedals. I would be leery, too, of the possibility of less grip a domed pin might provide. Definitely not looking for less grip on a flat pedal.
I ride flat pedals and would say I'm about middle of the road in terms of aggressive riding single track. I enjoy the drops and jumps that aren't completely insane, and it's these features where I've come off the pedals due to poor foot position and less than adequate control coming into the lip of of a jump. In the few instances where that happened, I was far more concerned for my jewels than my shins since the seat is the next stopping point for the body that has only air under its feet.
At any rate, your grip on a flat pedal is chiefly provided by an adequate amount of well placed pins that have a decent amount of height to gain excellent purchase into a rubber sole riding shoe.  Other factors like platform size and a nice dished shape are helpful as well, but ultimately it is the pins which make the foot stay in place.
I ride Shimano XT flat pedals with the long, 6mm pins on both sides of the platform. My properly positioned foot is stuck to the pedal as if I were clipped in.  Speaking to your concerns specifically, I'll use the XT pedals (PD-M8140 is the Shimano model number) as an example, although there are certainly other flats on the market with similar features I'm gonna relate. The XT flats come with short, 3mm, pins installed. These pins have rounded upper body and in the center is a 2mm hex tool hole. The bottom is an M3 thread that goes into the platform until the flanged part of the upper pin stops at its seat in the platform. So there are your round profile pins.
Also provided with the pedals are long pins these also have an M3 thread that terminates at a small flange. Above that the business end, is a 6mm tall, cylindrical pin that has a round, flat top and the hex tool hole at the center.
Both sides of the platform have pins. You could if you wanted have one side short pins and the other side long pins. You could even mix short and long pins on the same side, perhaps installing the short, round ones in the holes along the long edge of the pedal where you'd most likely scrape your shin should you come off the pedals.  I, myself, would not prefer the short pins at all for reasons mentioned above, but wanted to alert you to the possibilities.
Overall flat pedals are the best for developing skills on since you need to have good technique to, say, bunny hop.  Also the ability to come off the pedals quickly can be comforting, though one easily get stuck on a flat pedal (I've endo'd a few wheelies not being able to get my feet off the flat pedals and having no more leg extension to kick out off of them), and getting unclipped can be lightning fast with experience (both in technique of the clipless system and anticipating trouble).

The issue for me with SPDs is clipping back in. If you don't get it right first time, every time you can end up going into stuff with your foot in a bad position and prone to slipping off.  I'm thinking of times like stopping at the top of a challenging descent to allow some room between members of a group. I use M424s which have a cage as well as the cleat; they're reasonably secure but not very ergonomic with the axle under the arch of my foot if for some reason I don't want to be clipped in.

Also the person in front coming to a sudden stop on a climb tests your unclipping speed, but not having to take a moment to unclip leaves you more choice of where to put your foot down and actually find the ground

I presume you are riding of proper shoes designed for flats. If you are on 'street trainers' this would be my first recommendation. While the pins on good flats can do a lot of damage, you should not really be separating that often.
Less aggressive pins, or removal of pins and using fully molded pedals, will lead to more encounters between you shin and the pedals. You may merely reduce scaring only to replace it with bruising of the shin, or worse, more crashes and more damage elsewhere.
Given you appear to be wanting to push your limits (which is awesome), and find clipless unacceptable (completely acceptable), perhaps you need to consider increasing the aggressiveness of you pedals so your feet remain in contact more often. A foot in contact with pedal means no chance of shin to pedal contact (ignoring the undesirable obvious :) ).  Another approach while learning is protection, consider shin guards and wearing protective long trousers (hot and sweaty, but that washes off painlessly at the end of ride).  This will mean you do not have to compromise your bike setup and riding, and can walk away from "learning opportunities" unscathed and ready for another attempt.

When I ride flats on my MTB I use either running shoes or approach shoes/light hiking shoes.  They grip really well, to the extent that when I forgot that I wasn't clipped in and tried to rotate my foot I couldn't, and for a moment thought my cleat was stuck.  I tend to fit SPDs for long solo rides which often have a fair bit of road to get to the interesting bits, but prefer flats in a big group

@ChrisH it depends on the shoe's tread and rubber. My (old) Brooks Cascadia trail runners are terrifying on flats as the lugs prevent the pins from engaging. Vans slip-ons OTOH are pretty dang good. But nothing beats e.g., 5-10's Stealth rubber with the shallow dot pattern.

@PaulH Yeah, I wore skateboard shoes for MTB until I got Five10s. I have 1-sided Crank Bros pedals on my mountain bike, but the Five10s are happy on either side of the pedal.

Comment was aimed at the OP, who is clearly having problems with the shoe/pedal interface.  If the shoes are working well, keep using them.

On my flat pedals the pin thread are M4 and I replaced mine with M4x6mm to fasten half-toe clips on them.
The flat pedals should come with a special wrench to remove the pins.
Take one pin off or better yet, if you have spare ones, take one to the hardware shop and try to match the pin thread with those in the metal screw isle, taking into consideration the length for your application.
Ask for help if need too. Some shops don't mind opening a packet to test the thread matches your sample.
If you don't mind, take the pedal off the bike and take it with you to the hardware shop and that way you can test the thread of the screws.
On the attached image, you can see the packet of black screws I've used.
I suggest you don't replace all pedal pins with round head screws, but just the ones you suspect to be the most like to cause damage to your shin.
My flat pedals are on a commuter bike and I don't have any experience with MTB riding.
I don't know if the half toe-clip idea is appropriate for MTB riding.
I would think it could catch on something if up-side-down and through you out of balance.
Having said that, if you want to try it, it's up to your discretion.
I have more photos with other details to share if you are interested.
Hope this helps.

